# ¿Tiene nombre esta construcción gramatical?

Tags: gramática, letras-de-canciones

En una de las canciones de Lunnis de Leyenda, [la que trata de Quevedo](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiop7yKy7XVAhWESxoKHePIDCEQtwIIJjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rtve.es%2Finfantil%2Fserie%2Flunnis%2Fvideo%2Fvideoclip-quevedo-espia%2F3983743%2F&usg=AFQjCNEs1ECKHHfHR0na-FJ3PohtKJf2uw), la letra dice algo así (marca de tiempo 01:30):

> Y al verle la guardia reconoció su cara famosa le delató.

Nótese que en realidad son dos oraciones:
- *Y al verle la guardia reconoció su cara*
- *su cara famosa le delató*

Pero en la canción, se superponen ambas en "*su cara*", produciendo un curioso efecto de transición en el que cuando crees que aún no ha terminado la primera frase, te das cuenta de que en realidad ya estás en otra distinta.

¿Tiene algún nombre este tipo de construcción, donde se usa un elemento común para solapar dos frases, de manera que no se pueden separar sin que una se quede "coja" como Quevedo?

<sub>**Nota**: Imagino que la letra escrita original tendrá una o varias comas en algún lugar de la frase, para dejar claro dónde se produce la elipsis, o incluso un pronombre que se quedó fuera al grabar la toma ("la guardia *lo* reconoció" tendría sentido); pero vamos a suponer que no, que la frase es tal cual la he escrito yo. **El objetivo de la pregunta no es analizar cómo sería la oración correcta**, lo que me interesa es esa curiosa manera de juntar las dos frases en una :)</sub>

Comment: Es posible que la idea sea "Y al verle, la guardia reconoció su cara; (lo cual, por ser) famosa, le delató."

Comment: Las canciones no siempre son ejemplo de gramaticalidad. Una construcción donde se superpone una palabra o una frase que es esencial tanto para la oración anterior como para la posterior, sea por economía o para hacer un juego de palabras, simplemente no es una construcción gramatical. Cuando lo que se solapa es un sustantivo o una frase nominal, justamente se utiliza un pronombre relativo. De lo contrario, tendríamos construcciones agramaticales como ésta: *Reconocí su rostro estaba cubierto por un velo" en lugar de la gramatical: Reconocí su rostro QUE estaba cubierto por un velo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece un **zeugma**, que, según la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma)

> ...Es una figura de construcción sintáctica que consiste en utilizar una sola vez una palabra común para varias unidades análogas de la oración (un verbo para varios sujetos, un adjetivo para varios sustantivos, etc.), aunque ésta se refiera a otras más del periodo, solo se expresa en uno de ellos y ha de sobrentenderse en los demás. Consiste en la elipsis en una oración de un término enunciado en otra contigua segura.

Los ejemplos de la Wikipedia son bastante más simples que el tuyo, así que no estoy para nada seguro de esta respuesta.

Ojo, que la definición de "zeugma" que da Wikipedia no es la misma que da la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQwABIN).